# match a string with text and store the next text

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a string which contains some text (in Greek language) which was extracted from a pdf.

How can I found a particular text lets say `id.name: 123` and then store the number 123?

Comment: did you try `String.indexOf("id.name:")`?

Comment: If I'm right, you have key for search *id.name* but what pattern of value (*123*), that you want to store? Or value always is number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find using a regular expression:

```
  String s = "Έχω ένα string που περιέχει κάποιο κείμενο ( στην ελληνική γλώσσα ), "
        + "το οποίο εξήχθη από ένα PDF .\nΠως μπορώ να ιδρύσω ένα συγκεκριμένο κείμενο "
        + "ας πούμε id.name : 123 και στη συνέχεια να αποθηκεύσετε τον αριθμό 123";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("id\\.name \\: (\\d+)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  if(m.find()){
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
  }
```

Regards.

Comment: Thank you! να ' σαι καλα! :)

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do it, you can try regular expressions,

for instance let's suppose we have a string call s1 that contain "today is monday" and we can find the word monday, you can do that by:

```
String matcher = "today is monday"; 
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(".*monday.*");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(matcher);
        boolean b2 = m2.matches();
        if(b2 == true)
        {
            System.out.println(p2 + " found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(p2 + "no found");
        }
        }
```